# Updating a counter in a python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in Python as follows:

```
comment_obj=
[{'food_id': '-KCRZfJMGvYkofzskfRv',
  'food_name': 'Lazeez Special Cheese Kabab',
  'text': 'Lazeez Special Cheese Kebab were completely drool worthy',
  'time_stamp': '',
  'user_id': '-KBIcIgaIOYh2G8hLrYj',
  'user_name': 'Arjun Nambiar'},
 {'food_id': '-KCRZfJMGvYkofzskfRv',
  'food_name': 'Lazeez Special Cheese Kabab',
  'text': 'This is heart attack on a plate.So yummy and gooey',
  'time_stamp': '',
  'user_id': '-KBIcIgfu1V735jviWrk',
  'user_name': 'Samir Madhavan'},
 {'food_id': '-KCRZfJMGvYkofzskfRv',
  'food_name': 'Lazeez Special Cheese Kabab',
  'text': 'The molten cheese on this chicken was just awesome',
  'time_stamp': '',
  'user_id': '-KBIcIggKo4I7Bkn-N48',
  'user_name': 'Febin Sathar'},
 {'food_id': '-KCRZfJRMgLjlqzKZzCI',
  'food_name': 'Chicken Reshmi Kebab',
  'text': 'Covered in a velvet coating of egg,this was so yumm',
  'time_stamp': '',
  'user_id': '-KBIcIgaIOYh2G8hLrYj',
  'user_name': 'Arjun Nambiar'}]
```

As is evident,the time_stamp value is empty.I need to update the time_stamp value in every dict such that the time_stamp in the succeeding  dict is one more than the previous dict. This is how i tried doing this:

```
epoch_time = 1459408412
for d in comment_obj:
d.update((k, epoch_time+1) for k, v in d.iteritems() if k == "time_stamp")
```

But this updates the time_stamp everywhere as 1459408413 and the counter does not increase.What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
epoch_time = 1459408412
for d in Obj_comment:
    epoch_time += 1
    d.update((k, epoch_time) for k, v in d.iteritems() if k == "time_stamp")
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use the shorthand version of that `epoch_time+=1`

Comment: Thanks, @chris-sprance.  Updated based on your feedback

Comment: not at all @Amistad ! Sometimes our thoughts just get stuck in a rut and, in fact, I had such a problem at work today.  I have found that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging is very helpful

Comment: @Amistad looping  over the keys in the dictionary  and use `if` statement to compare the current key to `time_stamp` is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you shouldn't loop over the keys in the dictionary or use the `update()` method just to update one key. Simply use a `dict` lookup.

```
>>> epoch_time = 1459408412
>>> for element in comment_obj:
...     epoch_time = epoch_time + 1
...     element['time_stamp'] = epoch_time
... 
>>> [element['time_stamp'] for element in comment_obj] # Just to confirm all elements are updated.
[1459408413, 1459408414, 1459408415, 1459408416]
```